# Selected value is not selected in drop down list

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using `genericlist` to get dropdown list in CodeIgniter.

Here is my controller code to get dropdown list of question status:

```
$question_stat= $this->mdl_mcb_data->getStatusOptions ('ques_status');      
array_unshift($question_stat,$this->mdl_html->option('','Select Question Status'));
$active = 1;
$question_status = $this->mdl_html->genericlist($question_stat,"question_status",array('class'=>''),'value','text',$active);
```

Here is my view page part:

```
<tr>
        <th><label><?php echo $this->lang->line('status'); ?>: </label></th>
        <td><?php echo $question_status;?></td>
</tr>
```

When I use firebug to see the html part, it shows:

```
<tr>
    <th>
    <label>Question Status: </label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <select id="question_status" class="validate[required] text-input" name="question_status">
            <option value="">Select Question Status</option>
            <option value="0">Inactive</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="1">Active</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

That is exactly what I want to be selected. But in the dropdown list, selected value is not displayed as selected.

**Note:**

No code error at all. Firebug shows the desired result selected. 
But, in the dropdown list, selected value is not selected. What might be the reason?

Comment: Can't be an error in this small snippet. It works fine in jsFiddle. Do you have some JS ocde which could affect this? However, then the live code (not the original code) should still be shown in Firebug and reveal the error.

Comment: Nope.. At the top of view page, there is only `$(document).ready(function()` function but there are no parameters that affect the dropdown list.

Comment: When you check this are you doing a simple reload (F5) or a full page reload (Shift+F5)? When doing a simple reload, Firefox will preserve changed form elements' states (such as selects), whereas a full reload will reset them to their default as specified in the HTML.

Comment: Full page reload is also not working..

Comment: @Samutz : I found the solution, check it please..

Comment: @Lukas : I found the solution, check it please..

Answer (score 0):

I got the tricky solution to my own question. I just added following code at the top of the view page:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    cancel();
    showquestionList();
    $('#question_status').val('1');     
    $("#frm_question").validationEngine('attach', {
      onValidationComplete: function(form, status){ if(status==true){savequestion();}}  
    });
})

</script>
```

Here, what I did was I just added the following line of code:

`$('#question_status').val('1');`

And it worked perfectly.

Comment: This is not a solution, honestly. It's just a patch because it "overrides" the problem but does not really solve it.

Comment: Yup.. this is just a tricky solution. I did alot of research but could not find the best solution.. :) What might be the best solution??

Comment: I think that the problem is somewhere else, not where you posted. Try the code with another browser and/or another machine